# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization: Dealing with Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, orthogonal-matrices, gram-schmidt

A complex valued matrix "A" has n columns a_1 through a_n. Elements of these columns are complex numbers.

The orthogonal complex valued matrix U of A has n columns as well u_1 through u_n. 
u_1 is same as a_1.

Projection of column a_x on u_y is given by the formula:

```
P = [(a_x.u_y) / (u_y.u_y) ] [u_y]   => Equation-1
```

The term (a_x.u_y) or for that matter (u_y.u_y) results is essentially dot product of two complex valued column vectors resulting in a complex value.

Let us assume for the sake of discussion that:

```
a_x.u_y = a1 + b1 i
u_y.u_y = p1 + q1 i
```

From here, I can even compute the division resulting in another complex value:

```
[(a_x.u_y) / (u_y.u_y) ] = r + s i
```

The question now is: Should I take the absolute value of r + si and multiply it with u_y in Equation-1, or should I multiply r+si as-is to elements of u_y.

Comment: $u_y\cdot u_y$ is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

- I am not sure if you are aware of this, but the dot product of two complex vectors $u$ and $v$ is $u \cdot v = \bar{u}_1 v_1 + \cdots + \bar{u}_n v_n$. This is sometimes written as, $u^* v$ or $u^\dagger v$  where $u^*$ or $u^\dagger$ denotes the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of $u$.
- Based on the above definition, do you see why $u_y \cdot u_y$ is always real?
- Finally, to answer your actual question: no, you do not need to take any absolute value; the [Gram-Schmidt formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) holds for any appropriate dot product.

Comment: I do not have a strong background in mathematics and I have certainly learnt from your answer. Thank you very much.